# Why do we use hashes when comparing memory is better for things like pipeline state?

Tags: hash, graphics, vulkan

When people make a renderer using a graphics API such as Vulkan a common thing to do is to hash the pipeline object state so that you reuse the one already created instead of unnecessarily creating a new one if an identical one already exists. Hashing, although ideally they should yield different values for different byte/data arrays, are not guaranteed to be free of collisions, so that two different sets of bytes can yield the same hash value. Comparing the two byte arrays directly does not allow for a false positive in ensuring the data is identical. When sending data from one location to another, say over the internet, it's not possible to compare with the original/source data because you don't have it, however when creating a renderer and comparing two pipeline states you do have both sets of data, so why isn't it better to do a memory comparison instead of hashing?

Comment: ... are you actually asking why it's better to do a quick test that rapidly excludes 99.9% of cases and only doing the expensive test only on rare occasions? I mean, this is hashing 101 stuff: you do the cheap thing a lot so that you don't have to do the expensive thing very much.

Comment: @NicolBolas When do you do the expensive test though? You change pipeline state, the new state ends up hashing to an already existing hash, so you bind the existing pipeline without doing the expensive check. Then your pipeline state isn't correct, the algorithm doesn't work. The only way the algorithm works is if you do the expensive check every time. This is what I don't understand about hashing, how do you actually ensure this doesn't happen, despite however unlikely it is?

Comment: @NicolBolas Also, on the subject of what's more expensive, hashing probably involves a bitshift and/or a couple of arithmetic operations per byte, and memcmp is probably a conditional check, which would be more CPU cycles, BUT they could probably do 4 or 8 bytes at a time. Is it that obvious that a memcmp will be slower?

Comment: The example you gave says *nothing* about binding pipeline state. You talked about not creating a new pipeline if you already had an identical one bound. This was presented as a creation-time check, not a bind-time check. The latter doesn't make sense anyway, as you'd just check to see if the pointer you wanted to bind was equal to the one already bound.

Comment: "*Is it that obvious that a memcmp will be slower?*" In the example you gave, you create a hash of a pipeline when you create it. When you create a second pipeline, you make a hash from that and compare it to the first pipeline's hash. When you create a third, you hash it and compare it to the previous *two* pipeline's hashes. Etc. For N pipelines, you create N hashes but do O(N^2) comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main optimization is finding the matching pipeline, not the cost of a single memory compare.

If you rely on linear memory compares then you need to search through the whole list of available pipelines to find the pipeline that matches the current state. This is an `O(num_of_pipelines)` list search, with an `O(sizeof_pipeline)` memory compare per comparison. So total complexity is `O(num_pipelines) * O(sizeof_pipeline)`.

With a hash-map you pay `O(sizeof_pipeline)` cost to generate the initial hash, but  with a good hash and hash map data structure you should get close to an `O(1)` lookup (if you have a good hash function and enough root bins). So cost is one hash generation and one comparison unless you have collisions, so "big O" cost is `O(sizeof_pipeline)`.

Given the number of states and shaders for a game is finite it's also often possible to prove that collisions won't happen for your game content set, so you can even avoid the actual byte-by-byte compare on hit most of the time.